# Regular expression to find last match in XML output

Tags: regex

I have been working for days to learn regex so that I can extract the last match out of an xml output of a test from a scientific instrument. The instrument buffer can hold multiple tests and I am only interested in the last (most recent) test. I can't figure it out!

```
<Ticket class="SAMPLE" serialno="6000SP210134" versions="FP6000;Main:V1.25;COM:V1.7;D:V1.11;TEC:V1.6">
<Measurement>
 <SampleId>6</SampleId>
 <DateTime>2022-10-28T15:16:22</DateTime>
 <Value>300</Value>
 <Unit>mOsmol/kg</Unit>
<DeviceCode>6000SP210134</DeviceCode>
 <CheckSum>50c5656fd477cbcd3b7a5036ba98a542</CheckSum>
</Measurement>
</Ticket>
<Ticket class="SAMPLE" serialno="6000SP210134" versions="FP6000;Main:V1.25;COM:V1.7;D:V1.11;TEC:V1.6">
<Measurement>
 <SampleId>7</SampleId>
 <DateTime>2022-10-28T15:18:55</DateTime>
 <Value>425</Value>
 <Unit>mOsmol/kg</Unit>
<DeviceCode>6000SP210134</DeviceCode>
 <CheckSum>50c5656fd477cbcd3b7a5036ba98a542</CheckSum>
</Measurement>
</Ticket>
```

I need match and return the last value from the last test <Ticket></Ticket> (the number of Tickets is variable). In this example it would be **425**.

I thought this might work, but it doesn't...
`\<Value>\d{2,4}<\/Value>.*\n$\`

This regular expression is executed and interpreted in a lab information management system called LabVantage, not in any language like perl, php, C, etc.  A regular expression is the only option I have.

Comment: Or maybe like this with a capture group `(?s).*<Value>(\d{2,4})</Value>` https://regex101.com/r/SA5d2Y/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I hesitate to ever suggest inline modifiers like `(?s)` because their support is not universal. `[\s\S]*` is almost always a better choice.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus That is correct, there is no universal support but there is quite some support https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#modifiers Universal support for a regex can be difficult with all the different flavors.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I finally found some info on their product and they supply a web SaaS. Your link shows that JS does not support inline modifiers. https://www.labvantage.com/our-platform/technology/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Cool :-) Then if it is JavaScript then `[^]*<Value>(\d{2,4})<\/Value>` https://regex101.com/r/7Zq4mI/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird So you woke up this morning and chose violence I see. Thanks for teaching me something that's seemingly **only** supported in JS 

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I will never choose violence :-) I hope my comments are not perceived that way. Feel free to add it to your answer if your want ( I can not vote twice though)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sorry, it's a meme that landed poorly. It's always interesting to learn something new!

Comment: Thanks all for your help. I've tried every pattern that has been mentioned in this post and they work in regex101.com, but they always fail in LabVantage. So, I'll need to get a hold of the company to see if I can get more specifications on their regex engine.

Comment: From a learning, standpoint, it has been very insightful. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to coax LabVantage to work with a regular expression in the ways recommend above. However, if any LabVantage user is looking to solve a similar issue, the way it was resolved was to use a Value Extraction Rule like this:

```
 extract /regex/ extract /regex/
```

or

```
extract /regex/ extract last number
```

This type of expression is not explicitly made a visible to the user but it still works. So the final code that did work is this:

```
extract /(?s).*Value>/ extract last number
```

Thanks all who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

LabVantage does not seem to publicly reveal their regex engine but if you have access to lookarounds then this should work:

```
<Value>\d{2,4}<\/Value>(?![\s\S]*<\/Value>)
```

- `<Value>\d{2,4}<\/Value>` - you know what this does, you wrote it =)
- `(?![\s\S]*<\/Value>)` - ahead of me, `</Value>` does not exist

https://regex101.com/r/XpbOdR/1

---

If lookbehinds are supported then you can get fancy like this to extract **only** the digits:

```
(?<=<Value>)\d{2,4}(?=<\/Value>(?![\s\S]*<\/Value>))
```

https://regex101.com/r/VCDURX/1